# in what condition phys_base is not 0?

Tags: linux, kernel, coredump, xen

phys_base is referenced in kernnel source code [__phys_addr()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/physaddr.c#L11) arch/x86/mm/physaddr.c
and crash also use it as a machine dependent parameter [e.g. --machdep phys_base=0x200000](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/crash.8.html)

```
unsigned long __phys_addr(unsigned long x)
{
    if (x >= __START_KERNEL_map) {
        x -= __START_KERNEL_map;
        VIRTUAL_BUG_ON(x >= KERNEL_IMAGE_SIZE);
        x += phys_base;
    } else {
        VIRTUAL_BUG_ON(x < PAGE_OFFSET);
        x -= PAGE_OFFSET;
        VIRTUAL_BUG_ON(!phys_addr_valid(x));
    }
    return x;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__phys_addr);
```

can you help to explain in what condition it is not 0, how it is defined/determined and why.

UPDATE: the debut of "phys_base" can be found [here](http://people.redhat.com/nhorman/papers/ols-slides.pdf)

Comment: The phys_base is a delta between actual running physical address and linked physical address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily 0, because on some CPU architecture, the physical address is used to access things that are not memory. The way for the cpu to know what kind of interface or bus to use is by divivding the memory map.

I don't know the x86 architecture, but on ARM for example, you can have things like this :

- from 0x00000000 to 0x0fffffff, external flash is accessed.
- from 0x10000000 to 0x1000ffff, internal memory mapped register are accessed
- from 0x80000000 to 0x9fffffff, sdram or ddr is accessed.

In this case, phys_base would be 0x80000000.
So it is determined by the cpu or the chipset on x86. See [this](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/motherboard-chipsets-memory-map) for an example
memory map.

Comment: So, is `phys_base` the physical memory address at which the kernel image is loaded? And `x` is a virtual address, I suppose, right?

Comment: no phys base is not necesarrily where the kernel is loaded. It is where the segment of physical memory where the kernel is loaded start.

Comment: i think no, 'grep code /proc/iomem' shows the kernel text starts from 01000000 but phys_base is 0 in my machine.

Comment: @shodanex: how's that different? Does the kernel relocate itself?

Comment: @DynoFu: isn't that .text address a virtual address?

Comment: @Alex: relocation is architecture dependant. Don't forget there is usually a bootloader, so the kernel could be at any adress. Kernel virtual adress are usually in the 0xC0000000 range. See cat /boot/System.map.[kernel_version]

Comment: http://www.linux-archive.org/crash-utility/487567-how-do-debug-kdump-kernel-using-xen-dump-core-file.html this has some hints there is a second crash kernel kexec booted to take the original crashed kernel memory dump. i have not yet fully pieced it up...

Comment: I know about bootloaders, just not familiar with Linux code. Thanks.